# How can I control the rate of http requests in a JS script running on an online web game?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, web, bots

I am trying to build a learning bot for an online internet game. As part of the code we have the following function:

```
    oefTimer: function() {
        var start = Date.now();
        /*
         bot logic
        */
        setTimeout(userInterface.oefTimer, (1000 / bot.opt.targetFps) - (Date.now() - start));
    },
```

It's a function I didn't wrote. part of the logic is depends on the ability to send http requests and get responds to them (this is done using $.ajax from JQuery).

Now, the problem is that oefTimer is to fast and sends a lot of http requests, so I wanted to increase the time between each call to a function using setTimeout (so less requests will be sent). but when I did this, when the game ended, some of the requests have never been sent and I got the following error in the console:

```
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
```

Since in the original code the time between each call to oefTimer considered the Fps of the game, I guesses there is a connection.

How can I solve this problem? my aim is the control the rate of the amount of requests sent per some time unit.

Comment: I would completely seperate the ajax logic from the fps logic, with its own timer. I mean, you need the fps timer to run with high frequency and the ajax logic with rather low frequency.

Comment: yes, but how can I do that? I use a JS script to send the http request, and it's the same script the runs the bot. also, what is fps logic? do you have any useful information i can read?

Comment: Well fps logic is pretty much what you got already. I'm assuming this because of 'bot.opt.targetFps'. To create a seperate logic just add a new function...something like ajaxTimer instead of oefTimer...

Comment: I managed to solve that problem by avoiding sleep and also sent\d request only one time in 10 passing over the code. do you know where i can read more about fps logic in order to understand it?

Comment: I just called it fps logic.... by that I just meant the game logic that runs at fps-rate, so basically the code you already got. I'm not really sure what kind of game it is (realtime multiplayer?) so i cant really point out any tutorials.

Comment: It is a realtime multiplayer, yes :).